# C# string length is wrong

Tags: c#, string, sockets

I want to read data from socket.

The value of the result is the same as the data which socket send.

but I print debug info,the result length is very large,not string length which I see.

The length is the same as mySockeet.SendBufferSize.

How to change the code to make the length of result variable is correct.

```
public string readSocket() {
    String result = "";
    if(theStream == null)
       return "";
    if (theStream.DataAvailable) {
      Byte[] inStream = new Byte[mySocket.SendBufferSize];
      theStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
      result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream);
      Debug.Log(result.Length + " "+ mySocket.SendBufferSize);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Bytes are not the same as Chars.

Comment: a `String` is unicode and uses 2 bytes per character.

Answer (score -1):

I already fix that
Just change to this below

```
int length = theStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream, 0, length);
```

Comment: You missed the code demonstrating where length comes from. I've added it so that your answer is useful for other people.